# Calling member function from event listener callback function in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class, events

I need to call a member function from the callback function in an event listener which is also in another member function. Here is a simplified example:

```
class C {

  finished() {
    console.log ('over');
  }
  
  timer() {
    console.log('started')
    setTimeout(function fct() {
        this.finished();
    },500);
  }
}


let c = new C();

c.timer();
```

I get the following result : `Uncaught TypeError: this.finished is not a function"`. I understand that the callback function is no longer member of the class C.

Is there a way to call the `finished()` member function from the callback function?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/94zy18md/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this`

```js
class C {
    finished() {
        console.log('over');
    }

    timer() {
        console.log('started');
        setTimeout(function fct() {
            this.finished();
        }.bind(this), 500);
    }
}

let c = new C();
c.timer();
```

or just hand over the function

```
this.finished
```

which keeps the reference of `this`.

```js
class C {
    finished() {
        console.log('over');
    }

    timer() {
        console.log('started');
        setTimeout(this.finished, 500);
    }
}

let c = new C();
c.timer();
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the `setTimeout` callback will refer to `window` object not the `C` object, So you need to `bind` the `setTimeout` callback with the `C` object

```js
class C {

  finished() {
    console.log ('over');
  }
  
  timer() {
    console.log('started')
    setTimeout(function fct() {
        // ... some code.
        this.finished();
    }.bind(this),500);
  }
}


let c = new C();

c.timer();
```

Or you can use the arrow function which will make `this` will refer to the `this` of the outer scope.

```js
class C {

  finished() {
    console.log ('over');
  }
  
  timer() {
    console.log('started')
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.finished();
    },500);
  }
}


let c = new C();

c.timer();
```